# Get 'n' number of documents started from specific document in MongoDB collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Is this possible to get `n` number of documents from the collection, and fetching should start from specific object. e.g. if a collection has 100 documents then I need 10 documents started from 46 [ specific id ]. i.e. 46-55

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return products_model.find({'from_id' : 9677270841774}).limit(limit).exec((err, records) => {
    if(err)
        reject(err)
    else    
        resolve(records)
  })
})
```

Edit: The original document structure is as follows:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("6128a0d9cf34c208c30e6800"), 
    "id" : 3238425384636, 
    "title" : "i3jMH8CHPWY6Ru18KrmsDGdiyl2qDuFjxXD1M4yCzJHrOmSF8v", 
    "body_html" : "This is body", 
    "vendor" : NumberInt(1), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6128a0d9cf34c208c30e6805"), 
     "id" : 30336405569734,
},
{},
{},
{},
{}
```

and the API is

> http://localhost:3000/products.json?since_id=30336405569734&limit=10

Comment: You could create an array with 10 ids starting with the one you have. So you get `var arr = [46,47,48, ...,55];` and use it like this `.find({ from_id: {$in: arr }})`

Comment: I have more than 75 lac records in collection, Don't want to go with array processing iteration and all

Answer (score 2):

Example with 10ids, we want to get 4 ids starting from 4

- filter id>=4
- sort asceding id
- limit 2

For you data you want read the query string and then you want,   `id>=30336405569734` and `limit 10` .(numbers not strings)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a6Q8-psmYsa)

You can use the aggregation in mongoose.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "id": {
        "$gte": 4    // "$gte": 30336405569734 (for your data)
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 2    //  "$limit": 10 (for your data)
  }
])
```

Or write a find in mongoose, i don't use mongoose but i think it will be like this.

```js
products_model.find({ id: { $gte: 30336405569734 } })
  .sort({id: 1})
  .limit(10)
  .then(products => {
    console.log(products)
  });
```

or

```js
await products_model.find({ id: { $gte: 30336405569734 } })
  .sort({id: 1})
  .limit(10));
```

Comment: what about this code return products_model.find({'id': since_id}).limit(limit).exec((err, since_product) => {
     if(err) {
      reject(err)
     } else {
      
      if(since_product.length >0) {
       return products_model.find({_id: {$gt: since_product[0]._id}}).limit(limit).exec((err, records) => {
        if(err)
         reject(err)
        else 
         resolve([...since_product,...records])
       })
      } else {
       resolve({"message": "Product Not Found"})
      }
     }
    })

Comment: Because I do not have "_id" by default , I have value in  since_id variable which will get the column name as id from collection. and id can have random number in random order

Comment: if you can give an example of the data, and what result you want to get, to make the query for your data, i dont use mongoose but the query you want seems simple.

Comment: i hope the update helps, i didn't chage the query only replaced _id with id, i also tried to write it with a mongoose find, if you dont want to aggregate.